# Page contents in Navbar not filling the screen:

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, navbar

[Click here for image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plFlq.png)
Basically I sourced the code from getbootstrap.com but the search bar and search button are not being right-aligned in the navbar. Have tried to selectively align the search option but to no avail. Would live it if anyone helped. Thank you.

Here is the code:

````
```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can give margin and padding to the linking icons/navigation items to occupy more space of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclose your items ul and form inside a div with d-flex

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex">
<div class="d-flex align-items-start">
<ul>
  <li>...
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="d-flex ">
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```